# Did something very uncharacteristic, not sure where to go (Contains Jade Regent spoilers)

Tags: pathfinder-1e, player-characters

Disclaimer: This involves events from the Jade Regent AP. Spoilers will exist.

So I have a dilemma and I'm really not sure how to go from here. I basically did something very out of character because I don't do good RP on the fly;  I had a plan, forgot step one and things went downhill from there.

We started the session after having found the TotallyNotViking prisoner beneath Brinewall. Our social character had just failed to talk to her and was in the process of walking out with her weapons. Step one of my plan was to stop him or just take the weapons so he wouldn't leave with them. I forgot.

My character is a Skald (Bard/Barbarian hybrid class) and a gnoll. He's fairly kind-hearted since he was raised by Koya (cleric of Desna). He tried talking with her by expressing that the guy walking off with weapons had an oath of protection to keep and the like, this didn't really go over well. I didn't take Diplomacy so I naturally failed the DC25 roll to try to get her to listen.

So I somehow, after forgetting to stop him walking off with the weapons, decided the reasonable thing to do was to walk off with her armor. Leaving her without anything and telling her she may as well not have them since she was going to starve to death.

This is naturally very very very out of character (and is in character for a character of mine in a very different game). My Skald got into an argument with the face of the group about this and stormed back into the room and through the other side, tossing her armor in front of her cell. Which now had been broken out of. So we have an angry TotallyNotViking likely to come after us.

My main issue is that basically everything I did was completely out of character for my Skald. I thought of possible development, but it wouldn't make sense to have done all that. Naturally it's very much too late to take it back.

I kind of feel like I've damaged the character concept pretty badly and I'm not sure what to do now. We're on break until our next session since we finished at Brinewall, but I still can't think of a way for it to make sense for the character. (For the player it was because I emulated the wrong character).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how easy this will be to try and answer, in as much as there probably isn't a single true answer, but I'll try and explain what I'd do.

### Own it

Your character snapped. He was frustrated that his attempt to help had been rejected and he acted rashly. This happens to the best of us.

I think most of us would probably describe as ourselves as at least "fairly kind-hearted" but that doesn't mean that we aren't prone to outbursts or the occasional bit of irrational behaviour. Everybody makes mistakes so apologise to those you offended (in character) and accept the consequences. You are correct when you said "it's very much too late to take it back."

Sometimes characters take you in directions that you weren't expecting to go in. Roll with it and just accept that this happened and it's a part of your character that even you didn't know was there!

Comment: Unfortunately the one I offended was an NPC who broke out and is probably going to come back to kill us. If you've done Jade Regent, it's the imprisoned Ulfen lady. Otherwise I'd have him apologise in a heartbeat.

Comment: @MaxKojote Ah, I meant more specifically to apologise to your party member with whom you got into an argument. Who knows, you might get to patch things up with the Ulfen lady at some point too!

Comment: Yeah, given the other party member is the in-character adoptive brother of my character, apologies would be a good idea! I'll just roll with him being frustrated and resorting to theft rather than assault.

Hopefully if/when we run into the Ulfen lady, we'll have a chance to make amends. DM accidentally let slip that she's supposed to be a major NPC and we kind of messed it up with unlucky rolls.